# Pass JSON from JQuery.load('file.php') after on file.php refresh?

Tags: php, ajax, twitter

I am really sorry if this is confusing, I really had no idea how to word this.

I have a Hybrid App, and I want to allow a user to log via Twitter.  I am using TwtterOAuth.  Using Ajax load, I am able to get the authorising page into the app I do this by setting a php file on a server, which the app calls.  This is then loaded into a div on the app, albeit a little messy.

But the user needs to sign in, and then authorise. Which I think is 2 refreshers.  On the last refresh it should send me the users tokens which I can then use in telerik backend to set up the user.  I am unsure how I can retrieve the JSON object out of the last refresh of the PHP file, and use it in the app.  Normally one would use $.getJSON.  But because there needs to be interaction, I am not sure how to do it ?

So I am using a modal div to load the auth:

```
$('#twitterModContainer').load('http:twcall.php');
```

Which shows me the authorise page on Twitter, waiting for the user to login, and click authorise.  How would one proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data as a second argument on **.load()** function.

```
$('#twitterModContainer').load('http:twcall.php',{ data: value });
```

This will get passed as arguments which you can latter call them on the script as :

```
$_POST["data"]
```

Comment: I am not looking to pass data to the PHP file, but retrieve it.  So I am looking to allow the user to action what is needed on the PHP side, via the div, and upon the refresh of the PHP, grab the content from sent from Twitter to the PHP file, and then into Javascript on the app ?

Comment: You can use .load() to get data from the server, and you can pass the second parameter to .load() to send data to the server.

Comment: Okay, so I could, in theory, put some code on the modal holding the content, to look out for a certain type of JSON object.  The the twitter process takes a few refreshers.  Once the right JSON is found, then save data into storage and close the modal ?

Comment: Because there is no value to send, i am getting syntax areas.  How would I go about using the `data` once it was loaded ?

Comment: Well the problem with the business logic on how you handle Twitter Auth is not covered on my answer as it should be a technical specific question, as for the communication with server and browser using .load() function you can check my answer.

Comment: Thank you Burimi.  I have looked, and i cannot see any examples of how to achieve what i am looking, and to be honest, your answer does not cover it either.  I can send information to, but not pass it back, while the user interacts with file at the same time.  But i do appreciate your time.